# Append title tag in whole content where it contain <a> tag

Tags: php, xml, dom, preg-replace

I have a dynamic content which have few  tags starting with "https://" and "http://". I need to append title for each anchor tag starting with "https". code which I am using not able to append dynamic title. for ex:

```
$str = '<a href= "https://www.google.com">some text </a>
<a href= "https://www.yahoo.com">some other text </a>';
```

The output string would be:

```
$str = '<a href= "https://www.google.com" title="dynamic title1">some text </a>
<a href= "https://www.yahoo.com" title="dynamic title2">some text </a>'
```

The code which I am using is:

```
$xml = '<foo>'. $content.'</foo>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXml($xml);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor) {  
    if ($anchor->hasAttribute('title')) {
        $anchor->removeAttribute('title');
    }
}
$newcontent =  $doc->saveHTML();
$pattern = '/(href=("|\')https)(:\\/\\/.*?("|\'))/';
$subject = $newcontent;
preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches);
for($i=0; $i< count($matches); $i++){
     $complete_url = $matches[0][$i];
     $get_prog_name = explode("//",$complete_url);
     if (strpos($get_prog_name[1],'www.') !== false) {
        $get_prog_name = explode("www.",$complete_url);
      }
         $prog_acro = explode(".", $get_prog_name[1]);

           if($prog_acro[0] == "ccc") {
          $progName = "Dynamic Title 1";
      }
       if($prog_acro[0] == "cec") {
           $progName = "Dynamic Title 2";

      }
   $replacement[] = 'class="tooltip" title=Requires&nbsp;CEB&nbsp;'.$progName.'membership&nbsp;login $1$3';
 } // end foreach loop
 $newstr =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement[0], $subject, -1 );
```

I want to replace title dynamically here. the problem is that when put preg_replace in the loop it prints whole content many time as it contain anhor tags.

Comment: Do not use Regular Expression to match/change XML. You already use the DOMDocument to remove the title attribute, why do you do not use it to modify/add it depending on the href attribute?

Comment: I don't really get it. What exactly do you want to replace? From your example, it wouöld be enough to add `"dynamic title"` to all `<a>`-tags...

Comment: @ThW: How can I modify/add it depending on href attribute. Any code example

Comment: @michi: you are right I want to add dynamic title with each anchor tag

Comment: You're already using hasAttribute() and removeAttribute(), try getAttribute() and setAttribute().